# How can I apply filter to Django modelform and return form to view in Django?

Tags: django, django-2.0

I am trying to get user details in model form to create a `Service` object.Instead of returning all users from my accounts app, I wanted to apply custom filter 'is_admin = False' in object filter but it is returning users without applying filter. Help me to achieve this....

### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Service
from accounts.models import User

class AddServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ['service','title','manager','serviceMobile','alternateMobile',
                  'latitude','longitude','city','street','landmark','keywords']

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddServiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['manager'].queryset = User.objects.all().filter(is_admin=False)
```

### views.py code

```
class AddService(LoginRequiredMixin, LogoutIfNotAdminMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('mlogin')
    permission_required = 'is_staff'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context={}
        context['city'] = City.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AddServiceForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
                return redirect('servicedata')
        else:
            form = AddServiceForm()
        return render(request, 'aapp/locations/service/uservicedata.html', {'form': form, 'context': context})
```

Comment: after making changes to the init method try restarting the server(manage.py runserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way for this while fetching objects we can filter using **limit_choices_to** in model fields like this...

```
manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, limit_choices_to={'is_admin':False})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my confusion before. But after going through some documentation, I came to know that inside `__init__` method, the `super` should be used after `self.fields`.

So your changes should be like:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.fields['manager'].queryset = User.objects.all().filter(is_admin=False)
    super(AddServiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Does that make a difference?

Comment: all() method does not guarantee to return a QuerySet everytime. Also why would you call all the objects and perform filter on them? It just increases another method call.

Comment: @Aswin Murugesh No of course it won't make any difference

Comment: @Sanip That's not how the querysets work - they're lazy evaluated, so calling `filter` after `all` makes no difference at all expect it removes the unnecessary function call and additional code.

Comment: @bonidjukic So the thing is that using only `filter` method also somehow involves calling both all() method with filter() method?